# ORA-00904 : invalid identifier in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a problem creating this table. I am using oracle to create a sql and I have already created the table ITEM but i cannot find the error in this one. Can someone explain where the issue is? This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE STOCK(
    STOCKID VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    MANUFACTUREDATE DATE NOT NULL,
    EXPIRYDATE DATE NOT NULL,
    QUANTITYONHAND number (4) NOT NULL,
    SELLINGPRICE number (4) NOT NULL,
    SIZE varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    ITEMID varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT STOCKID PRIMARY KEY(STOCKID),
    CONSTRAINT ITEMID_FK FOREIGN KEY
    (ITEMID) REFERENCES ITEM(ITEMID)
    );
```

Comment: FOREIGN KET should be FOREIGN KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two and a half issues:

- one is typo (foreign `key`, not `ket`),
- another is invalid column name - `size` is a reserved word, so - rename it to e.g. `c_size`)
- "half" of the issue is datatype - Oracle recommends us to use `varchar2`, not `varchar`.

After that:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE stock
  2  (
  3     stockid           VARCHAR2 (4) NOT NULL,
  4     manufacturedate   DATE NOT NULL,
  5     expirydate        DATE NOT NULL,
  6     quantityonhand    NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
  7     sellingprice      NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
  8     c_size            VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  9     itemid            VARCHAR2 (4) NOT NULL,
 10     CONSTRAINT stockid PRIMARY KEY (stockid),
 11     CONSTRAINT itemid_fk FOREIGN KEY (itemid) REFERENCES item (itemid)
 12  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

`size` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm) in oracle: .

Please rename the column.